# Call to deprecated function retry_on_eintr. retry_on_eintr(check_call, [sys.executable, 'setup.py', 'clean', '-a', 'bdist_egg', '-d', d]

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd, scrapyd-deploy

I have to deploy my scrapy project on scrapyd on windows server 2016. I am using the below command to deploy my project

```
scrapyd -deploy local
```

but it generates the following error

```
Call to deprecated function retry_on_eintr.
  retry_on_eintr(check_call, [sys.executable, 'setup.py', 'clean', '-a', 'bdist_egg', '-d', d]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: found any success yet?